# React PropTypes which not transmitted directly

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Should i write in propTypes and defaultProps a props like children, or invalid, pristine, submitting (redux-form), or t, i18n (react-i18next) and other?
What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure, you need to mention this props. Firstly, it makes your code more clear for you and other developers. Secondly, it helps in writing unit tests for the components. You may use side-packages with the propTypes for the libs to avoid duplications. Another possible solution is writing your own reusable propTypes.